# Is it possible to renew a British passport early?

Tags: visas, passports, uk-citizens, working-holiday

I am planning on going to Canada on a working holiday visa. I know you can renew UK passports with 9 months still valid on your passport and they add this to the new one, but can I apply for a new one now 11 months before it expires and they add just 9 months on or do I have to wait until October before I can renew as this would exactly 9 months before it expires?

Comment: I won't add an answer as I'm not sure about the first bit, but in terms of getting a new passport, there's no problem ever renewing a passport early if you need it. 

You can renew or replace your passport at any time. It costs £72.50 by post or £81.25 through the Post Office’s Passport Check & Send service. Time left on an existing passport is added to your new one - up to a maximum of 9 months - https://www.gov.uk/renew-adult-passport

Comment: you may actually have more luck if you split it into two separate questions, btw.

Comment: thanks guys. Yeh i wasnt sure whether you could only renew within those 9 months, good to know it can be renewed at any time so no need to wait and be in a bit of a rush.

Comment: since I see you've asked the canadian WHP one separately, I'm going to edit this one to be just about the passport, and move my comment to an answer. Let me know if that's ok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of getting a new passport, [there's no problem ever renewing a passport early if you need it](https://www.gov.uk/renew-adult-passport).

> You can renew or replace your passport at any time. It costs £72.50 by
>   post or £81.25 through the Post Office’s Passport Check & Send
>   service. Time left on an existing passport is added to your new one -
>   up to a maximum of 9 months.

Comment: The rules have changed since the original answer, and the official page https://www.gov.uk/renew-adult-passport/renew now says "Time left on your old passport will not be added to your new one."